# Error emulate android ionic framework

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app with ionic, but I can not emulate it in android to see their functions properly.
Here is the error when running the command to emulate
I'm using Ubuntu 4.14 Linux OS
    sandim@Inspiron-5448:~/projects/soucgApp$ sudo ionic emulate android

```
Running command: /home/sandim/projects/soucgApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/sandim/projects/soucgApp
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: /home/sandim/projects/soucgApp/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator
ERROR: Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
Error: /home/sandim/projects/soucgApp/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: have you set `andoid_home` enviroment variable in .bash_profile ?

Comment: `ERROR: Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. ` this is your problem.